# Elasticsearch + logstash space requirements Elasticsearch

Tags: couchdb, logstash, elasticsearch

I am planning to use elasticsearch + logstash with my couchdb on same server. What would be a recommended amount of storage that should be allocated for elastics search in my case considering the amount of data and same sever senerio ? Our web application is expected to have around 60/70 thousand records.

Many thanks,
Imad.

Answer (score 0):

60-70k records is not so much.
Let each record be a 100Kbytes(too much, but we want upper bound). It will be 6-7MB. 
I think you should log initial disk usage (df command may help you).
load your records and check df again to understand how much disk space you use by this records.